# How to Unmelt the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below, and i want to keep one of the best rating columns here.

**Original DataFrame:**

```
skunumber   category    overallrating   rating  reviews
123         Cat1        1               1       20
124         cat1        2               2       23
```

for that I'm melting then dataframe and rename overallrating to rating. Finally drop duplicates if any and again i want to convert the melted data frame original format.

**Melted Dataframe looks like this:**

```
skunumber   category    attribute      attributeRawValue
123         Cat1        overallrating  1
124         cat1        overallrating  3
123         Cat1        rating         1
124         cat1        rating         2
123         Cat1        reviews        20
124         cat1        reviews        23
```

DataFrame looks like after rename of overallrating to rating and removing duplicates.

```
skunumber   category    attribute   attributeRawValue
123         Cat1        rating      1
124         cat1        rating      2
123         Cat1        reviews     20
124         cat1        reviews     23
```

and Finally I want dataframe back as original one.

```
skunumber   category    rating  reviews
123         Cat1        1       20
124         cat1        2       23
```

I tried performing this with pivot option, this works if we have one index column but here i have 2 columns.

sample code:

```
messy = pd.DataFrame({
    'row': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [4, 5, 6],
    'c': [7, 8, 9]})
           
tidy = pd.melt(messy, id_vars='row', var_name='dimension', value_name='length')  

messy1 = tidy.pivot(index='row', columns='dimension', values='length')   

messy1.reset_index(inplace=True)
messy1.columns.name = ''
```

In my case I tried to pass index as `['skunumber', 'category']` it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add another column to parameter `id_vars` in [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = df.rename(columns={'overallrating':'rating'})
tidy = pd.melt(df, 
               id_vars=['skunumber','category'],  
               var_name='dimension',
               value_name='length')  
tidy = tidy.drop_duplicates()
print (tidy)
   skunumber category dimension  length
0        123     Cat1    rating       1
1        124     cat1    rating       2
4        123     Cat1   reviews      20
5        124     cat1   reviews      23

messy1 = tidy.set_index(['skunumber','category','dimension'])
             .length
             .unstack()
             .reset_index()

messy1.columns.name = None
print (messy1)
   skunumber category  rating  reviews
0        123     Cat1       1       20
1        124     cat1       2       23
```

Another simplier solution with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) (by default keep only `first` value) and last [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.rename(columns={'overallrating':'rating'})
tidy = df.set_index(['skunumber','category'])
         .stack()
         .drop_duplicates()
         .unstack()
         .reset_index()

print (tidy)
   skunumber category  rating  reviews
0        123     Cat1       1       20
1        124     cat1       2       23
```

If works with real data you can easy get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Then solution is bellow or another answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['Cat1', 'Cat1', 'cat1'],
                   'overallrating': [1, 5, 3], 
                   'skunumber': [123, 123, 124], 
                   'reviews': [20, 30, 23], 
                   'rating': [4, 2, 2]})

print (df)
  category  overallrating  rating  reviews  skunumber
0     Cat1              1       4       20        123
1     Cat1              5       2       30        123
2     cat1              3       2       23        124
```

Nedd [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns which creates new `index` before `reset_index` (here `skunumber` and `category`) and aggregate some function like `mean`, `sum`, `max`, `min`, `first`...

```
df = df.rename(columns={'overallrating':'rating'})
tidy = df.groupby(['skunumber','category'])['rating'].max().unstack().reset_index()
print (tidy)
   skunumber category  rating  rating
0        123     Cat1       5       4
1        124     cat1       3       2
```

EDIT by comment:

If duplicates need some aggregate function like `max`, `first`, `sum`, `mean` with `groupby`:

```
print (df)
   skunumber category  overallrating  rating  reviews  color colorShade
0        123     Cat1              1       1       12  White        Red
1        123     Cat1              1       4       20   Pink      Green
2        124     cat1              2       2       23  Black       Blue

df = df.rename(columns={'overallrating':'rating', 'colorShade':'color'})
g = df.groupby(['skunumber','category'])

tidy1 = g['rating'].max().unstack()
print (tidy1)
                    rating  rating
skunumber category                
123       Cat1           1       4
124       cat1           2       2

tidy2 = g['color'].first().unstack()
print (tidy2)
                    color color
skunumber category             
123       Cat1      White   Red
124       cat1      Black  Blue
```

And then `concat` data together:

```
df = pd.concat([tidy1, tidy2],axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   skunumber category  rating  rating  color color
0        123     Cat1       1       4  White   Red
1        124     cat1       2       2  Black  Blue
```

Another solution with `pd.lreshape`:

```
tidy = pd.lreshape(df, {'rating':['rating','overallrating'], 'color':['color','colorShade']})
print (tidy)
  category  reviews  skunumber  color  rating
0     Cat1        1        123  White       1
1     Cat1       20        123   Pink       4
2     cat1       23        124  Black       2
3     Cat1        1        123    Red       1
4     Cat1       20        123  Green       1
5     cat1       23        124   Blue       2

tidy = tidy.drop_duplicates(['category','skunumber'])
print (tidy)
  category  reviews  skunumber  color  rating
0     Cat1        1        123  White       1
2     cat1       23        124  Black       2
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, your solution worked on my sample data. I will try using with the actual data.

Comment: Jezrael, I tried with the actual data I'm getting **"ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"** error.

Comment: also I tried to use the solution given by you, but i have more columns and which are also string columns.

Comment: Unfortunately you need `groupby` with `unstack` solution, can you explain more with sample your problem with multiple text columns?

Comment: consider I have 2 more columns along with ratings and reviews. color and colorShade.
     color  colorShade
123    Red    Red
124    blue   blue

Comment: consider I have 2 more columns along with ratings and reviews. color and colorShade.
skuNumber|color|colorShade
------------------
123|Red|Red
124|blue|blue

Comment: I want to perform same steps along with ratinigs and reviews columns. and i want to have one color column

Comment: thanks Jezrael for the steps, yes we could do this way. but in my case some times columns will vary and i want to make to work dynamically. Is there any simple step which you suggest me.

Comment: Ok, then more dynamic solution is with general reshaping by `lreshape` with `drop_duplicates`.

Comment: thanks Jezrael for coming up with many work around, but there is a limitation even with lreshape. suppose for color we have one more column **colorSchema** and then if i add that  to the lreshape step.

Comment: tidy = pd.lreshape(df, {'rating':['rating','overallrating'], 'color':['color','colorShade','colorScheme']})

Comment: getting error **ValueError: All column lists must be same length**

Comment: hmmm, there is different size? Try `pd.lreshape(df, {'rating':['rating','overallrating'], 'color':['color','colorShade','colorScheme']}, dropna=False) `

Comment: what about `tidy = pd.lreshape(df, {'rating':['rating','overallrating', 'rating'], 'color':['color','colorShade','colorScheme']})` ?

Comment: tried this option with my actual data i got another error **all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions** .

Comment: I am confused, but maybe need unique values in values of dict, so try before `lreshape` use `df['rating1'] = df.rating` and then `tidy = pd.lreshape(df, {'rating':['rating','overallrating', 'rating1'], 'color':['color','colorShade','colorScheme']})`. If it does not work, I have no idea what canbe problem. :(

Answer (score 1):

You require [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to integrate multiple objects as it's `index` argument. But, do note that if there are duplicated values corresponding to these set of indices, then their aggregation would produce the averages which is by default (`aggfunc=np.mean`). If you'd want to sum these values, you need to specifically do so by providing `aggfunc=np.sum`.

```
piv_df = df.pivot_table(index=['skunumber', 'category'], columns=['attribute'], values=['attributeRawValue'])
piv_df.columns = piv_df.columns.droplevel(0)
piv_df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
```

[image]

---

To obtain `df`:

```
data = StringIO(
'''
skunumber   category    overallrating   rating  reviews
123          Cat1          1             1        20
124          cat1          2             2        23
''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['skunumber', 'category'], 
             var_name='attribute', value_name='attributeRawValue')
df.loc[df['attribute']=='overallrating', 'attribute'] = 'rating'
df.drop_duplicates()
```

[image]

Comment: Solution which works with duplicates also, only I think is important give notice about default aggregate function `mean`.

Comment: @jezrael, Good catch! I've added a small note to my post.

Comment: Nickil, i tried to use your steps also but some how I'm not getting required output.

Comment: I'm getting **DataError: No numeric types to aggregate** error.

Comment: You need to provide the `values` argument to use `aggfunc`(default mean). *See edit*

Comment: Nickil, since i have string columns how can use agg function.

Comment: If they are numerical strings and you want to treat them as numbers and perform various aggregations, then `.astype(int)/.astype(float)` would suffice. Else, you could still aggregate them by joining them separated by a delimter of your choice (use `aggfunc=lambda x: ','.join(x)` to separate each by a comma delimiter)